# Error:Bitmap size Exceed VM budget, when converting image to ARGB_8888

Tags: android, jakarta-ee

Here is my code:
    File file = new File(Path to Jpeg File size is 700kb);

```
InputStream in = null;

        try  {
    in = new BufferedInputStream(new     FileInputStream(file));
     }
     catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
       bitmap =BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
       bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
```

Please help i get error in this copy line i want to make its ARGB_8888 image.Need Help :(

Comment: What are the dimensions of the image?

Comment: I must want the image in this form ARGB_8888 , I am using a tesseract OCR Library , and it require the bitmap image in this form so it can OCR the Image  ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reduce the memory usage.

From you code, you first decode stream to one bitmap, and then copy it, which means you create two large bitmap objects.

You don't need to decode and then copy it, you can try

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
// You can try value larger than 1
options.inSampleSize = 2 // If set to a value > 1, requests the decoder to subsample the     original image, returning a smaller image to save memory.

// Decode bitmap
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options)
```

In this case, there's only one bitmap created. And you set inSampleSize to large values to reduce the loaded bitmap size.

Comment: Great Job MAN Please Also reply to my [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652863/selecting-the-rectangular-area-in-image) post as well Thanx advance